# Proxy not created in Angular 14

Tags: json, angular, typescript, proxy, angular14

```json
{
    "/family-book-base/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

When I start my angular application using `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`, it starts properly, but the proxy path is not created.

Note:
Using the same proxy file with Angular 11 it's working fine.